# Serializer doesn't have fields inside __init__ function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

There is a Serializer `FooSerialyzer` with the field `bar`:

```
class FooSerialyzer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  bar = serialyzer.CharField()
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    # some custom fields logic
```

**Problem:** Now there are some unittests in the project. The problem is that there is one test that fails - only if ran after other tests.

The tests are to complex, so there is really no point to post them. I have put a debugger inside the `__init__` and here is what I get.

**When test ran alone:**

```
(Pdb) self
FooSerialyzer():
  bar = serialyzer.CharField()
```

**When test ran after other tests:**

```
(Pdb) self
FooSerialyzer():
```

---

**Question:** what could cause the Serialyzer to not have fields when ran **after other tests**? The tests are located in separate files, and use separate setup - can't even imagine how they could influence one another.

Comment: hmm, in debug mode are you sure that you check `FooSerializer` after `super().__init__()` called?

Comment: Yes, checked it. For the test ran alone - it has fields before and after `super().__init__()`. For the test ran after other tests - no fields at any time.